# Image does not fit in UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have some base64 data and am trying to put it in my image, which I can do but I can't get it so that it shrinks to just fill the imageView and not make it bigger, here is what I am doing

```
NSString *base64 =[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"data:image/png;base64,%@", dataString] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:base64];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    rdCell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    rdCell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    [rdCell.imageView setImage:image];
```

I have also tried this

```
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:base64];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    rdCell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [rdCell.imageView setImage:image];
```

But then I see the image larger than the original size of the image view, why won't it stay inside?

Thanks

Comment: what is rdCell? show us where are you allocating imageView?

Comment: @SamB rdCell is my UITableViewCell that contains the image view I will post more about it above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use contentMode `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` instead!

Comment: @spenf10 Why did you accept an answer after stating it didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

`UIViewContentModeScaleToFill` should do trick, but you need to be sure that you are able to see the whole image view onto your screen and giving a certain content size would helpful.